# React Native ListView not updating when cleared DataSource

Tags: android, react-native

I updating component's state like

```
if (!this.state.filtered) {
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(allData),
        filtered: false,
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(filteredData),
        filtered: true,
    });
}
```

it's work fine when `filteredData` is not empty. but when `filteredData` is a empty array, the ListView not updating after `setState` (function `renderRow()` and `rowHasChanged()` not called also.).
I tried calling `listView.forceUpdate()` but useless. 
my react-native version is 0.14.0 and running on Android 5.0

===update===
After calling `setState()`, using `console.log(this.state.dataSource)` results is

```
{ 
  _rowHasChanged: [Function],
  _getRowData: [Function: defaultGetRowData],
  _sectionHeaderHasChanged: [Function],
  _getSectionHeaderData: [Function: defaultGetSectionHeaderData],
  _dataBlob: { s1: [] },
  _dirtyRows: [ [] ],
  _dirtySections: [ true ],
  _cachedRowCount: 0,
  rowIdentities: [ [] ],
  sectionIdentities: [ 's1' ] 
}
```

In my case, the structure of variable `allData` is like this:

```
var allData = [[{id:1, name:'tom'},{id:2, name:'jerry'}], [...], [...]];
```

and the `filteredData` is just a empty array `var filteredData = [];`
I modified `filteredData` to `var filteredData = [[null]]` and the listView can be rendered correctly, don't know why, it just works :(

Comment: clonewithRows will always take input as an Array

so make sure you assign the dataSource itself as null or an empty array into the clonewithrows

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly because I do not see the initial state of your datasource (this.state.dataSource) in your code, but I think the problem may be that you need to have datasource set up like this:

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
```

Than, call set state like this:

```
this.setState({
    filtered: true,
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(filtereddata)
});
```

I've set up a full working project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/iPfYoQ). Also, code is pasted below. I hope this helps.

```
https://rnplay.org/apps/iPfYoQ

'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ListView
} = React;

var alldata = [{name: 'chris'}, {name: 'jennifer'}, {name: 'james' }];
var filtereddata = []

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      filtered: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(alldata)
    };
  },

  onPress: function() {
    if (!this.state.filtered) {
        this.setState({
            filtered: true,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(filtereddata)
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            filtered: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(alldata)
        });
    }
  },

  _renderRow: function(rowData) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {rowData.name}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
  },

  checkFilter: function() {
    if (this.state.filtered) {
      return 'red';
    } else {
      return 'white'
    }
   },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
                <TouchableHighlight 
      onPress={ () => this.onPress() }
      style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height:70, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                        <Text style={[{color: this.checkFilter(), fontSize:22, textAlign: 'center'}]}>Change Filter</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <View style={{marginTop:10}}>
         <ListView 
           renderRow={this._renderRow}     
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource} />                         
      </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer and sample!  I updated my question and did you have other suggestion? thanks again.